# Laravel 5.5 - whereDay for 2 days?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Using eloquent, I am trying to get all users regardless of year who registered on February `28` OR `29` (in case of a leap year):

```
// If leap year, get feb 28 and 29 users
$users = \App\User::->whereMonth('created_at', '=', '02')
                    ->whereDay('created_at', '=', '28')
                    ->whereDay('created_at', '=', '29')
                    ->get();
```

The above does not work when we add the extra `29` check here:

```
->whereDay('created_at', '=', '29') // does not work because of whereDay '28' above
```

Ideally something like this would work, but it does not exist in the api:

```
->whereDayIn('created_at', ['28','29'])
```

Any idea how to get the users for both days February `28`/`29`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$users = \App\User::whereMonth('created_at', '=', '02')
                    ->whereIn(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), [28,29])
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you query to:

```
// If leap year, get feb 28 and 29 users

$days = [28, 29];

$users = \App\User::whereMonth('created_at', '02')
                    ->where(function($query) use($days) {
                        foreach ($days as $day) {
                            $query->whereDay('created_at', '=', $day, 'or');
                        }
                    })
                    ->get();
```

OR

```
// If leap year, get feb 28 and 29 users

$days = [28, 29];

$users = \App\User::whereMonth('created_at', '02')
                    ->whereIn(DB::raw('DAYOFMONTH("created_at")'), $days)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: hmmm... I get an error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWhereDay()`

Comment: Any way to avoid the foreach?

Comment: @SagarGautam you are right! I have updated the answer again

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier Nice to see :D

Comment: hmmm... not fetching any rows for me even though there is data using `->whereIn(DB::raw('DAYOFMONTH("created_at")'), $days)` Not sure why nothing is returned by the query...